# is it necessary to install testng plugin when testng dependency is added in maven project

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have selenium maven project in which the dependency for the testng is added. But i'm not able to see the run as TestNG in the "run" options. should i install testng plugin for eclipse

Comment: Yes you have to install the plugin.

Comment: That worked. Thank you Robby Cornelissen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For eclipse, the plugin is required if you want to run as TestNG.  The only other alternative to run tests from eclipse would be, if you have the maven plugin installed, then you can still trigger your tests by running as mvn test, but testng plugin would definitely simplify stuff.

If you are running from maven either from command line or from Jenkins, then plugin is not required.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intellij Idea as IDE, then it will be available by default so don't need to even have it as dependency in maven but in case of eclipse you have to explicitly install it.